# JNDI Architecture: JNDI API, Service Provider, SPI?

Tags: java, jndi

I have read JNDI online tutorial from oracle using this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/overview/index.html).

It has the following diagram:

[image]

With respect to this, I have following questions:

1) JNDI API - Is this just a specifications / interfaces which comes as part of J2SE? That is, when we call some method of this API, does this do the real work OR it internally calls someone else, provided by third party?

2) Naming Manager - I didn't get this at all, nor is there any explanation provided? Is this part of the J2SE? Is it API?

3) JNDI SPI - What is this? What is the relationship between JNDI API and JNDI SPI? Do JNDI API call JNDI SPI internally for doing the real work? Who provides these JNDI SPI?

4) What is the meaning of Service Provider?

I am not able to understand this, can anyone help me understand in simple words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) JNDI API - Is this just a specifications / interfaces which comes as part of J2SE?

Yes.

> That is, when we call some method of this API, does this do the real work

No.

> OR it internally calls someone else, provided by third party?

Yes.

> 2) Naming Manager - I didn't get this at all, nor is there any explanation provided? Is this part of the J2SE? Is it API?

It's a bit of behind-the-scenes glue that helps JNDI providers by doing a lot of the boilerplate for them. Or else I don't know what it means.

> 3) JNDI SPI - What is this? What is the relationship between JNDI API and JNDI SPI?

See below.

> Do JNDI API call JNDI SPI internally for doing the real work?

Yes.

> Who provides these JNDI SPI?

The container, or in some cases the JRE, such as the RMI provider, the LDAP provider, the DNS provider, the COSNaming provider.

> 4) What is the meaning of Service Provider?

The code that provides the service. I don't think this is such a mystery. The code that implements the interfaces comprising the API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  One more question on JNDI SPI. If I want to use say, openLDAP, would the implementors provide the SPI for openLDAP?

Comment: Sigh. I've answered that. The provider for LDAP is part of the JRE. Sometimes I wonder why I bother.

Comment: I thank you for your valuable inputs and I respect your time you take to help members. You did mention that J2SE do have the LDAP provider. As there can be different number of LDAP implementations from different vendors , that was the reason for me asking this question. Is the LDAP provider which is bundled with J2SE capable of communicating with any kind of LDAP implementation? I am sorry for not able to fully understand this, and at the same time I am respecting your time and the help you extend. Best Regards

Comment: LDAP is a protocol. Therefore there is no need for more than one provider. So there is only one provider. In the JRE. As I said. Twice. Three times now.

Comment: Same applies to RMI; DNS; and COSNaming. Oddly enough, that's why they are all provided with the JRE.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, helped to clarify the things. At the same time, I really want to thank you for your time for helping the members here. Thanks again.